# Android JSONObject Post Volley using StringRequest

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'am a bit confuse now as I have asked a question related to JSON decoding on the PHP side. I focus there on decoding JSONobject POSTED from Android Volley using stringrequest. I was able to create a good code concerning to inserting data to MySql and I forgot that I'm still having a bad configuration on the client side. Now I'm getting "E/Volley: [215] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500" I will post my code here both on Android and PHP side. Please guide me accordingly. Really tired here. Hope anyone help me.

CLIENT SIDE:

```
public void testOrder (ArrayList<String> order_id,
                                      ArrayList<String> uname,
                                      ArrayList<String> prod_name,
                                      ArrayList<String> prod_id,
                                      ArrayList<String> quantity,
                                      ArrayList<String> branches,
                                      ArrayList<String> totalPrice,
                                      int itemIteration){

        JSONObject obj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        final JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIteration; i++) {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            Log.d("OBJECT_COUNTER", String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                obj.put("itemCount",   itemIteration-1);
                obj.put("order_id",    order_id.get(i));
                Log.d("ORDER_ID",      order_id.get(i));
                obj.put("uname",       uname.get(i));
                Log.d("USERNAME",      uname.get(i));
                obj.put("prod_name",   prod_name.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_NAME",     prod_name.get(i));
                obj.put("quantity",    quantity.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_QUANT",    quantity.get(i));
                obj.put("branch",      branches.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_BRANCHES", branches.get(i));
                obj.put("totalPrice",  totalPrice.get(i));
                Log.d("TOTAL_PRICE",   totalPrice.get(i));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }


            try {
                finalobject.put("ORDERLIST", jsonArray);
                test = jsonArray.toString();
//                Toast.makeText(this,test,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.TRY_JSON_POST,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PlaceOrder.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Log.d("Response",response);
//
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PlaceOrder.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("ORDERLIST", finalobject.toString());

                return params;
            }
        };
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT); strRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(strRequest);

    }
}
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$content   = file_get_contents("php://input");
$response  = json_decode($content, true);
$orderlist = json_decode($response['ORDERLIST'], true);
//$count     = count($response);

for($x=0;$x<=count($response);$x++){
  foreach($orderlist AS $row){
     $id=$row[$x]['order_id']; 
     $uname=$row[$x]['uname'];
     $query_parts[$x] = "("."'".$row[$x]['order_id']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['uname']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['prod_name']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['quantity']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['totalPrice']."'".")";
  }
}

$sql_1 = "INSERT INTO `order` (`order_id`, `uname`) VALUES ('$id', '$uname')";
$sql_2 = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id, uname, prod_name, quantity, total_price) VALUES ".implode(',', $query_parts);

 if ($con->query($sql_1) === TRUE) {
       if ($con->query($sql_2) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error2: " . $sql_2 . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
 } else {
    echo "Error1: " . $sql_1 . "<br>" . $con->error;
 }

 } else {
        echo "FAILED JSON POST";
 }
```

REMOVED SOME STATEMENT FIRST TO PREVENT THE VOLLEY.ERROR

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$content   = file_get_contents("php://input");
//$response  = json_decode($content, true);
//$orderlist = json_decode($response['tag'], true);
//$count     = count($response);

$response = json_decode($content, true);
$orderlist= $response['ORDERLIST'];

echo $content;

 } else {
    echo "NO POST";
 }
```

I'm getting these bunch of code so I guest server side received my JSONObject

```
ORDERLIST=%7B%22ORDERLIST%22%3A%5B%7B%22itemCount%22%3A1%2C%22order_id%22%3A%226794%22%2C%22uname%22%3A%22jordan%22%2C%22prod_name%22%3A%22ABC%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%2C%22branch%22%3A%22Dapitan%22%2C%22totalPrice%22%3A%2223500%22%7D%2C%7B%22itemCount%22%3A1%2C%22order_id%22%3A%226794%22%2C%22uname%22%3A%22jordan%22%2C%22prod_name%22%3A%22AMD+Kaveri+A4-7300+APU+HD8470D+2-Core+2GB+500GB+CPU+Package%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%2C%22branch%22%3A%22Dapitan%22%2C%22totalPrice%22%3A%2223500%22%7D%5D%7D&
```

SIMULATED DB OPERATION AND IT IS WORKING

```
$content = '{"ORDERLIST":"{\"ORDER_LIST\":[{\"order_id\":\"1756\",\"uname\":\"jordan\",\"prod_name\":\"ABC\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"branch\":\"Dapitan\",\"totalPrice\":\"23500\"},{\"order_id\":\"1756\",\"uname\":\"jordan\",\"prod_name\":\"AMD Kaveri A4-7300 APU HD8470D 2-Core 2GB 500GB CPU Package\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"branch\":\"Dapitan\",\"totalPrice\":\"23500\"}]}"}';
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
$response  = json_decode($content, true);
$orderlist = json_decode($response['ORDERLIST'], true);
//$count     = count($response);

for($x=0;$x<=count($response);$x++){
  foreach($orderlist AS $row){
     $id=$row[$x]['order_id']; 
     $uname=$row[$x]['uname'];
     $query_parts[$x] = "("."'".$row[$x]['order_id']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['uname']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['prod_name']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['quantity']."'".","."'".$row[$x]['totalPrice']."'".")";
  }
}



$sql_1 = "INSERT INTO `order` (`order_id`, `uname`) VALUES ('$id', '$uname')";
$sql_2 = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id, uname, prod_name, quantity, total_price) VALUES ".implode(',', $query_parts);

 if ($con->query($sql_1) === TRUE) {
       if ($con->query($sql_2) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error2: " . $sql_2 . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
 } else {
    echo "Error1: " . $sql_1 . "<br>" . $con->error;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the data against `key` `"tag"` but on `server side` you are fetching from key `"ORDERLIST"` as `$orderlist = json_decode($response['ORDERLIST'], true);`. Either in `getParams` remove the param and send the complete json or on server side change to `$orderlist = json_decode($response['tag'], true);`

hope this helps.

Comment: I changed from the server side the to 'tag' but no luck

Comment: You don't have to use `json_decode` multiple times as you did `$response  = json_decode($content, true);
$orderlist = json_decode($response['ORDERLIST'], true);`, you should do instead `$response  = json_decode($content, true);
$orderlist = $response['ORDERLIST'];`

Comment: I'm having a Volley.Server.Error.

Comment: It shows the Server error, that means Server is unable to handle the request I guess. You should change it at first place?? Secondly, Is there any timeout error, have you checked in `onError`?

Comment: I don't know which way to go now, when I click a button from the client side I received this volley.server.error. Right now I remove some codes on the server side and error is gone.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/0UhhY I always assumed that when it does echo from the webpage it will also display on the Toast message from the android device. But it displaying nothing on the toast.

Comment: it looks that you are getting `TimoutError`. Set the timeout to 60seconds and then check. Try this `RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        strRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);` and then add this request to the queue.

Comment: Futhermore, apart from Timeout, the link you shared, you are expecting the request json against key `ORDERLIST` but from android you are sending against key `tag`, Please match the keys before initiating the request

Comment: I changed everything to ORDERLIST but no display on my Toast message

Comment: Please post the updated code of server and client? Plus I have asked you to put the `timeout to request` because you are doing DB operations which might delay your response because by default Volley timeout is 2.5 seconds i guess.

Comment: Ok sir I have added timeout to request. I updated my post and remove some code from the server side to remove the error on android toast. Do you want me to put back the codes or not from the server. I want to divide and conquer my problem here.

Comment: In the server code, your loop statement is `for($x=0;$x<=1;$x++){` do you want to run 2 times?

Comment: I updated again my post again. Please do look. Regarding to the loop. It is supposed to be dynamic depending on the size of $response.

Comment: It looks like that the iterating over json and then saving to database code is a culprit. Please verify your server code and see the example that how to iterate JSON array and then save to Database. Furthermore, why you are not saving every entry to database while you were iterating the JSON array?

Comment: I have also now posted the simulated db operation, using a static defined JSON. Right now I don't know where I should start editing.

Comment: From the db operation, what its trying to do is to collect all the data from the JSONObject and store it in the $querry_parts[] array and using function implode() to insert the data to database one time only. My db has a foreign constraint so I need it to do it like this. I hope you get what i mean.

Comment: sir what the difference of passing passing actual JSONObject from JSONObject.toString?

Comment: Please show the map string of `getParams`? It looks like json is having issue.